# Running Hudson, Sonar and HA Proxy on the same server

Tags: ssl, haproxy, hudson

I am running Hudson, Sonar and HA Proxy on the same server (Doing this for the sake of a POC so do not have access to multiple servers.

I am Using HAProxy to enable SSL for both servers.

I can access each of these servers locally using the following urls 127.0.0.1:9000/sonar and 127.0.0.1:8088/hudson from the host

But when I try to remotely access the server using https:/52.X.X.X/sonar or https:/52.X.X.X/hudson I get

```
No data received
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I add a `default_backend sonar` to the HAProxy config i can run sonar but not hudson, and vice versa.

My HAProxy Config is like this

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode tcp
    # Set timeouts to your needs
    timeout client  1h
    timeout connect 1h
    timeout server  1h
    option http-server-close

frontend http
    mode http
    bind *:80
    compression algo gzip
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https
    mode tcp
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/buildserver.pem
    compression algo gzip

    use_backend sonar if { path_beg /sonar }
    use_backend hudson if { path_beg /hudson }

backend sonar
    server srv_sonar localhost:9000

backend hudson
    server srv_hudson localhost:8088
```

Any help on getting both sonar / hudson to run would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT** Final config file that works

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode http
    # Set timeouts to your needs
    timeout client  1h
    timeout connect 1h
    timeout server  1h
    option http-server-close

frontend http
    bind *:80
    compression algo gzip
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/buildserver.pem
    compression algo gzip

    use_backend sonar if { path_beg /sonar }
    use_backend hudson if { path_beg /hudson }

backend sonar
    server srv_sonar localhost:9000

backend hudson
    server srv_hudson localhost:8088
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config is setup to use `mode tcp` for the `frontend https` block.

Change it to `mode http` and you should be fine.

The reason is that HAProxy isn't decoding your HTTP requests, but rather just looking at layer 4 information (source & destination IP and ports).